# Trouble accessing a Singleton Class C++

Tags: c++, singleton

I am trying to write a singleton class for a centralized access point for game data from various classes. Here is what I have... just generic for now.

--> Singleton.h

```
#pragma once

class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* instance;
    static Singleton* Get();

private:
    Singleton() {};
};

 Singleton* Singleton::Get() {
    instance = new Singleton();
    return instance;
}
```

--> and in the main.cpp I attempt to call into existence the Singleton class

```
#include "Singleton.h"
Singleton* single = Singleton::Get();
```

--> and I get the following errors in MS Visual Studio

LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class Singleton * Singleton::instance" (?instance@Singleton@@2PAV1@A)    TimePilot84 E:\VC\TimePilot84\TimePilot84\main.obj  1

I do not understand how to instantiate this class if its constructor is private and if accessing the public constructor is public yet yields an err

I realize that I am not testing to see if the class exists before calling the constructor in the Get function and that I have no destructors as of yet.

I only make one single call to this function in main, and it will not compile.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: Generally recommended approach to Singleton: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `static` member.  This should be done in a .cpp file rather than in the header :

```
Singleton *Singleton::instance = nullptr;
```

Also note that the instance should only be created once, so `Get()` should look like this :

```
Singleton *Singleton::Get()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        instance = new Singleton;
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Alternatively, you could ditch the `static` member variable and implement `Get()` like this:

```
Singleton *Singleton::Get()
{
    static Singleton instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

The latter has the bonus effect of calling Singleton::~Singleton() when your program exits.

Comment: Perfect... thank you.  It would not let me define the static member in the header. I tried both methods as you wrote and they both worked. I ended up using the latter, much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define static variable instance. Add following after declaration of class:

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance = nullptr;
```